# Override existing properties with Groovy DSL delegate getter

Tags: groovy, dsl

In the example below I want to override *all* properties with my own delegate's logic. But I can only do that for inexistent properties, the ones known at the compile time remains the same.

Is it possible to process them all?

```
def dsl(Closure action) {
    action.delegate = new Object() {
        Object getProperty(String name) {
            println "overriding property [$name] => Ross"
            return "Ross"
        }
    }
    action()
}

dsl {
    def existingSymbol = "Joe"
    println "existingSymbol: $existingSymbol"
    println "inexistentSymbol: $inexistentSymbol"
}
```

Output:

```
existingSymbol: Joe     <--- expecting "Ross" here
overriding property [inexistentSymbol] => Ross
inexistentSymbol: Ross
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem in `def existingSymbol = "Joe"`

by using `def` you are declaring a new local variable that has maximum priority.

check the following code:

```
def dsl(Closure action) {
    def delegate = new Object() {
        Object getProperty(String name) {
            return "Ross"
        }
    }
    action=action.rehydrate(delegate,delegate,delegate)
    action.call()
}

dsl {
    def existingSymbol = "Joe"
    println "1 existingSymbol: ${existingSymbol}"
    println "2 existingSymbol: ${this.existingSymbol}"
}
dsl {
    existingSymbol = "Joe"
    println "3 existingSymbol: ${existingSymbol}"
    println "4 existingSymbol: ${this.existingSymbol}"
}
```

output:

```
1 existingSymbol: Joe
2 existingSymbol: Ross
3 existingSymbol: Ross
4 existingSymbol: Ross
```